# I have a navigation menu and I want that it's list items, on click, go to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, nav

sorry if this question has already been answered. I've tried searching for other answers but still couldn't solve it. I'm new to jQuery..

So, I have a navigation menu and I want that it's list items, on click, go to a specific div.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="overlay" id="nav-overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li ><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="intro">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="about-section">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="hero-section-1">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="contact-section">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And Jquery:

```
// Scroll to div

$(document).on('click','.nav-link', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

When I click on the links nothing happens, and in my console i get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: @fordareh thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to pre-fix the target with its selector:-

```js
// if the target is a class
$('.' + target).offset().top

// if the target is a id
$('#' + target).offset().top
```

Comment: just one more question, my navigation is a fullpage overlay, and when I click on the links I can see the page scrolling to the right section but my menu wont automatically close. how could I fix that?


    // Hamburger Menu

    $('#button-toggle').click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
       $('#nav-overlay').toggleClass('open');
      });

Comment: inside the nav click function, add `$('#button-toggle').toggleClass('active'); $('#nav-overlay').toggleClass('open'); `?